# Show AVG evaluation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I started SQL a few weeks ago so I'm fairly new at this! I encountered this exercise in my homework and i was a bit confused or unsure if i did them correctly! Im posting this here to check if i did any mistakes or not. If possible can you tell me if i did them correctly and in case i didnt maybe point out the mistakes and maybe provide some hints on how to fix them?

So this is the exercise

1. Given the following relational schema:

USER (SSN, NameU, SurnameU, City, YearOfBirth, UserType)

MOVIE (CodM, Title, Nation, Language, MovieStudio, Genre)

EVALUATION (SSN, CodM, Evaluation, Date)

a. For each user type, show the average evaluation given to movies produced by
"Marvel" (MovieStudio = "Marvel").

```
SELECT  AVG(EVALUATION)

FROM    EVAUATION E, USER U, MOVIE M 

WHERE   E.SSN=U.SSN AND E.CODM=M.CODM AND MOVIESTUDIO='MARVEL'
```

For the first part i'm a bit confused in the part where it says **for each user type**. I dont think it is correct but how do i show information about **each user type**

Comment: Are you sure that you copy the right schema definition? None of the table that you used in the query are described in the problem ...

Comment: damn you are right! im sorry!

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: wait really? i have some solved exercises in my uni portal and they used the commas in the from clause? what about the exercise?  how do i correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, nearly 30 years ago the ANSI-92 standard was adopted to replace using `,` for implicit joins between tables, instead using explicit `JOIN` syntax.  I strongly recommend avoiding any and all material that attempts to teach you that using `,` is correct; it's not, use `JOIN` syntax, it's already close to thirty years old...

Finally, you need to look at using `GROUP BY` as part of your aggregation, to get multiple results rather than just one...

```
SELECT
  U.UserType, AVG(EVALUATION)
FROM
  USER U
INNER JOIN
  EVAUATION E
    ON E.SSN=U.SSN
INNER JOIN
  MOVIE M 
    ON E.CODM=M.CODM
WHERE
  M.MOVIESTUDIO='MARVEL'
GROUP BY
  U.UserType
```

This will give one row per `UserType`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I didnt know